# List index error with dynamodb table query

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, mqtt, dynamodb-queries

I am developing a web controlled garden monitor based off a framework given here.

https://www.hackster.io/mokxf16/smart-garden-raspberry-pi-arduino-65c7b7

I get a list index error at line 52 on aws_pubsub_status.py. I have tried to enter an item in the "status" table manually through the aws mangagement console but that did nothing. 
The error is related to the line:

uStatus = data[0]['status']

Several parts of the framework design were deleted in the arduino files but I didn't think this would effect any of the MQTT and AWS related code.

I've tried manually entering 
an item in the table, deleting that section of code or deleting the entire loop.

```
loopCount = 0
while True:
  dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
  table = dynamodb.Table('Turbosprout_status')

  response = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('id').eq('Turbosprout_status'),
      ScanIndexForward=False
  )

  items = response['Items']

  n=1
  data = items[:n]
  uStatus = data[0]['status']
  status = uStatus.encode('latin-1')
  print(status)
  ser.write(status)
  sleep(4)
```

Should run without error.

Comment: How many elements are in the `data` list?

Comment: From what I understand the data list contains id's from the dynamodb table Turbosprout_status but I'm not sure. The only included markup was saying that the loop would run forever. Nothing about what the loop's purpose or function is for.

Comment: But *you* are running the code, presumably. Why don't you print out the `data` so that you know what it contains? This will help you to understand why you are getting a list index out of range.

Comment: What’s the data in the table? Is there any data in your DynamoDB table?

Comment: If you followed the tutorial and existing repo here https://github.com/chowzzzz/smartgarden/blob/master/aws_pubsub_status.py, note that the search is looking for the id_status KeyCondition, is the Key of your table called “Turbosprout_status” or something else?

Comment: Guys, bare with me I am a total noob to programming. I'm not sure how to print the data list but like I said there was no data in the dynamodb table. I believe the keycondition is 'id'